# CSS how to make an image clickable with this dropdown function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to make is a settings icon that you can click which then creates a drop down of options.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
// Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

/* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
            background-image: url("icons/settings-icon.png");
            background: #aeaba9;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 10px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
            background-color: #5f5f5f;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            overflow: auto;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .show {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title>Clickable Dropdown</title>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add the css line

background-image: url("icons/settings-icon.png");

but this doesn't do anything or throw an error. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to go about this.

Comment: have you tried to just add the id to the image so `<img src="icons/settings-icon.png" id="myBtn" />` in replace of the `button`

Comment: Simon, that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: ok will addd as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have it written:

```
background-image: url("icons/settings-icon.png");
background: #aeaba9;
```

The second line is overwriting the first line. You might want to reorder them or make the second line read more specifically `background-color: #aeaba9;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just add the id to the image so

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <img src="icons/settings-icon.png" id="myBtn" />
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

in replace of the button

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(../file.png);
```

you may want to try out using `../` before the file name